# Cast Object array to another array using GetType

Tags: c#, class, types, casting

I have `Object[] array1` and I know only Type of element

```
Type t = MyClass;
```

How can I get dynamically base type of array like `typeof(MyClass[])` ?

Edit:

I found:

```
Type type = ReferenceTypeComponent.GetReferenceObjectType(tItem);
Array destinationArray = Array.CreateInstance(type, oList.Length);
Array.Copy(oList, destinationArray, oList.Length);
```

Comment: i try t1.MakeArrayType() so i get Type MyClass[], there is another way?

Comment: the base type would always be `object[]` not sure what or why you want to get the type of the array - do you mean the individual items in the array?

Comment: maybe differently, I have object[] array1 and Type t1 = typeof(myclass), how can i create myclass[] array1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use List<> and then typecast using Linq.

```
List<Object> ListOfObjects = MyListOfObject; // Which contains List<Objects>
List<Type> parsedList = ListOfObjects.Cast<Type>().ToList();
```

Edit :  Here is an example on how to create a generic function when you don't know the type of class

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(int anyParameters)
{
    var results = new List<T>();
 var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();// Item here is the type of T
// DO whatever processing is to be done on Item.
    results.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: i cant use something like:
Type t1 = ...
arra.Cast<t1.GetType()>();

Comment: No, But you can use Type t1 =array.Cast<Type>().ToLIst();
Give the ClassName instead of getting type.
If you want to have a generic type. create a generic function.
which will have something like array.Cast<T>().ToList();

Comment: I have added a snippet see the answe

Comment: I have object[] array1 and Type t1 = typeof(myclass), how can i create myclass[] array1 ?

Comment: i have told you to use "T".
Can you post your code let me modify it.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can get dynamically base type of array?

The base type of the array is `object[]`. Period. You can put anything in it. You can put a `string` on index 0, and a boxed `int` on index 1. Of course, you can walk all values and get their type, but that should be prevented when possible.

If you don't want to go that unreliable way, you have to use a typed list type, like `MyType[]` or `List<MyType>`.

Comment: But I do not know what type I will receive. Type getArrayType(Type type)

Comment: Explain more why you don't know.

Comment: because the object array can be of different base type, so I want to use Type